# Инструмент для Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Часто приходится верстать страницы, и подбирать картинки/пиктограммы/иконки, однако надоедает по 10-40 картинок заливать на сервер, чтобы посмотреть как будет выглядеть картинка на сайте.

Есть ли инструмент для Google Chrome, который позволит не загружая фото никуда, показать как оно будет выглядеть на сайте?

Answer (score 4):

Правой кнопкой, `Inspect Element` — откроет `Developer Tools` (или `View - Developer - Developer Tools`)

Там можно динамически менять html, css, свойства. В т.ч. заменить в стиле `background: url()` картинки на локальный файл, чтобы посмотреть. Налету поиграть со стилями очень удобно!

Comment: Это баян. Вопрос был - есть ли "Инструменты разработчика" из web store у Google chrome что-то подобное? А про F12, нашли на что мне открыть глаза.

Comment: Баян-небоян, но свое дело делает. Что вы ожидаете увидеть от этой вашей тулзы? Возможность смены URL бэкграунда определенного элемента? Или SRC изображения? Ой, да ведь то же самое делают Developer tools!

Comment: Заниматься версткой, подкачивая картинки на удалённый сервер — идиотизм. У разработчика должен быть локальный сервер. 
Про `web store` в вопросе Вы не упоминали. Каков вопрос — таков ответ.

Comment: Ок, проехали, делаем всё как и раньше, по дедовски. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Такие рабочие вещи нужно делать в development среде. А так согласен, firebug и devtoolkit в помощь